# Refreshing CoreData Table?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, reloaddata

I can refresh any non-CoreData loaded tableView by calling `[nameoftableView reloadData];`

But when I call this on my CoreData loaded TVC it does not reload the table. **Does this work differently?**

It does update it contents if I stop and start the app again - so that it reloads the database, so I know it has the updated content in it.

Cheers Jeff

Comment: reloadData works for me when refreshing a UITableView that is populated from Core Data. There must be something else going on. Maybe post the method where you call reloadData?

Comment: If you are using NSFetchedResultsController, try sending executeFetch: to your fetchedResultsController instance.  In all likelihood it has cached the original results and it needs to refetch the fresh results.

Comment: try reloading TableView in viewWillAppear() and fetch from CoreData before reloading TableView

Comment: Hi I am still working on this - so far any reloading in any view is not working, however after looking in the SQL file I know the app is storing the data, so just got to display it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without details is difficult to know what is going on, but if you use a simple `NSFetchRequest` I think you need to execute the query and call `reloadData` again.

*A simple note*

I suggest you to use `NSFetchedResultsController` when dealing with Core Data and `UITableView`s. [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) has a tutorial on how to use that class in Core Data.
First of all it allows you to deal with a lot of data displayed in a `UITableView`. In particular, if for the `NSFetchRequest` you use with, you set a batch size, data will be retrieved in "batches". For example, the first 10. Then if you scroll the other 10 and so on...

In addition you can deal with data changes (update, insertion or deletion) for free using `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` class ([Reference NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)).

Hope it helps.